# Is the name of web application always the name of the war?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, xwiki

I'm trying to install XWiki on Tomcat. I have checked the web.xml and found:

```xml
<display-name>xwiki</display-name>
<description>XWiki Application</description>
```

But `localhost:8080/xwiki` returns error 404:

> description The requested resource (/xwiki) is not available.

I also found:

```xml
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>XWikiService</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/XWikiService</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

But the same problem:

> description The requested resource (//XWikiService) is not available.

Is something wrong with my installation? I didn't found any error in catalina.out.
But when I try war name:

> localhost:8080/xwiki-enterprise-web-4.1.2/

It works!

What should I check?

Comment: What does your post have to do with your title??

Comment: Thanks. Forgot about last point of question. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`display-name` in `web.xml` has nothing to do with the URL object used to access the resource, it is only a short name or description to display, used depending on the container. In Tomcat, it's used in the management application.

`url_pattern` should refer to a servlet, but you're probably missing some part of the object. webapps are typically referred to by the name of the WAR (depending on the container), so if your WAR (where `web.xml` is found) is named `xwiki-enterprise-web-4.1.2`, then you should try:

- `localhost:8080/xwiki-enterprise-web-4.1.2/XWikiService` to access the servlet, and
- `localhost:8080/xwiki-enterprise-web-4.1.2/` to load the webapp.

If the latter fails, then you might try to use the `welcome-file` attribute to default to loading a specific file.

What is it specifically that works when you load: `localhost:8080/xwiki-enterprise-web-4.1.2/`? Does this load your webapp? Do you just want to know the URL of the servlet? If so then try this: `localhost:8080/xwiki-enterprise-web-4.1.2/XWikiService`

Answer (score 5):

You need to configure the [Context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) in Tomcat. There are [several places](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) where you can define the context, and it's the `path` attribute that defines the "name of the web application" that you are looking for.